# How do I show $\liminf_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{'}(x)}{f(x)^{a}} \leq 0$ .

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

suppose that $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a differentiable and positive function. Show that for any $a>1$, it must hold that $\liminf_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{'}(x)}{f(x)^{a}} \leq 0$.

Can anyone suggest me direction for this question?

Comment: I am not sure if this will help a great deal, but I notice that when $a=2$ the function $\frac{-1}{f}$ is differentiable and always negative.

Comment: We can generalise the observation of @311411. $g(x) = \frac{f(x)^{1-a}}{1-a}$ is a strictly negative differentiable function for $a > 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\;g:\left(0,+\infty\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ the function defined as

$g(x)=\frac{f(x)^{1-a}}{1-a}\;$ for all $\;x\in \left(0,+\infty\right).$

Since $a>1$ and $f(x)$ is a positive and differentiable function on $\left(0,+\infty\right)$, it follows that $\;g(x)$ is a negative and differentiable function on $\left(0,+\infty\right)$.

Moreover, $\;g’(x)=\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)^a}\;$ for all $\;x\in\left(0,+\infty\right),\;$ therefore $\;\liminf_\limits{x\to +\infty} g’(x)=\liminf_\limits{x\to +\infty} \frac{f’(x)}{f(x)^a}=l\;.$

We have to prove that $\;l\le0\;.$

If $\;l$ were a positive real number, then there would exist $x^*>0$ such that $\;g’(x)>\frac{l}{2}\;$ for all $\;x>x^*.$

Let $\;x^{**}=x^*-\frac{2g(x^*)}{l}>x^*$ and, by applying Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem on $\left[x^*,x^{**}\right]$, there would exist $c\in\left(x^*,x^{**}\right)$ such that

$g(x^{**})=g(x^*)+g’(c)(x^{**}-x^*)>g(x^*)+\frac{l}{2}\left(-\frac{2g(x^*)}{l}\right)=0,$

hence $\;g(x^{**})>0\;,$

but it is a contraddiction because $g(x)$ is a negative function on $\left(0,+\infty\right)$, so it is impossible that $\;l\;$ is a positive real number.

Analogously, $\;l=+\infty$ also leads to a contraddiction.

Hence $\;l\le0$.

Comment: Good game Angelo !(+1)

Comment: Nice answer! Just an aesthetic question: why are you dividing the case $l \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $l = +\infty$? They both implies the existence of $x^\ast$ for any positive $\varepsilon$ smaller than $l$ (instead of $l/2$)

Comment: Of course you are right, but only when I was completing my answer, I became aware that I was forgetting the case $l=+\infty$, so I have added it eventually. Anyway the case $l=+\infty$ is very similar to the case $l\in\mathbb{R}^+$, so I think it is not necessary to change my proof.